# How to write the mdx equivalent to following sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssas, mdx, cube

I have the following SQL code in the Stored procedure in SQL server which feeds data to the reports. Now we are implementing the SSAS cube to process the data. I have a Fact table which has all the measures and degenerate dimensions. We are facing issues while converting below calculation into the MDX. This calculation purely depends on the Start Date and End Date parameters so it can not be done at the ETL time. It has to be performed when the client selects the Start and End date on the report.

Can any one help/ guide me  how i should convert below code into MDX? As a novice in MDX world, i am facing following issues

a. Lack of temp table like structure which help storing the temp data during processing.

b. Stored procedure are supported as the CLR or COM objects. Why SQL/ MDX procedure are missing?

Is it possible to perform the following calculations from the cube data?

```
Select 
    rundate ,Entity ,MasterEntity   ,TransactionDate    ,BuyOrSell  ,Quantity2  ,Quantity1  ,Quantity3  ,Quantity4  ,Profit1
    ,Profit2    ,Profit3    ,transactionId  ,closingtransactionId
into #TempData from [Fact_Test]
Where datediff(d,@StartDate,rundate)>=0 and datediff(d,rundate,@EndDate )>=0 order by rundate

Select Rundate,TransactionDate,BuyOrSell,Quantity2,transactionId,closingtransactionId 
into #ClosedTransactions from #TempData Where BuyOrSell = 'C'

Select 
    affected.Rundate AS 'OpenTransactionDate',  affected.BuyOrSell as 'OpenTransaction_BuyOrSell',
    affected.Quantity3 as 'OpenTransaction_Quantity1' , affected.Quantity1 as 'OpenTransaction_Quantity2',
    affected.Profit2 as 'OpenTransaction_Profit2',  affected.transactionId as 'OpenTransaction_transactionId',
    affected.closingtransactionId as 'ClosedTaxlot_ClosedingtransactionId'
into #AffectedOpenTransaction from #TempData affected
where affected.transactionId in (select distinct transactionId from #ClosedTransactions)
and affected.rundate between @StartDate and @PreviousDateFromEndDate and affected.BuyOrSell = 'O'

select 
    CLOSED.Rundate as 'ClosingDate',    CLOSED.Quantity2 as 'ClosedQuantity',
    CLOSED.transactionId as 'closingtransactionId', AFFECTED.OpenTransaction_transactionId as 'OpeningtransactionId',
    AFFECTED.OpenTransaction_Quantity2 as 'AffectedQuantity',   AFFECTED.OpenTransaction_Profit2 as 'Affected_Profit2',
    AFFECTED.OpenTransactionDate as 'AffectedTransactionDate',Convert(float,0) as 'Profit2_Adjusted'
into #TempProfit2
from #ClosedTransactions CLOSED
inner join #AffectedOpenTransaction AFFECTED 
on ( CLOSED.transactionId = AFFECTED.OpenTaxlot_transactionId   and datediff(d,AFFECTED.OpenTransactionDate,CLOSED.Rundate)>0 )

update #TempProfit2
set Profit2_Adjusted = case when AffectedQuantity <>0   then(ClosedQuantity * 1.0/(AffectedQuantity*1.0)) * Affected_Profit2    else 0.0 end

select 
    closingtransactionId,   ClosingDate,
    Sum( Case When datediff(d,AffectedTransactionDate,ClosingDate)> 0 Then Convert(float,Profit2_Adjusted) else 0.0 End ) as UnrealizedPNL_Adjusted
into #Profit2_Adjusted
from 
#TempProfit2
group by closingtransactionId,ClosingDate

select 
    MasterEntity,Entity, sum(Profit1 + isnull(Profit2_Adjusted,0)) as FinalProfit1,
    sum(Profit2 - isnull(Profit2_Adjusted,0)) as FinalProfit12,sum(Profit3) as Profit3,
    sum(Profit1 + isnull(Profit2_Adjusted,0)) + sum(Profit2 - isnull(Profit2_Adjusted,0)) + sum(Profit3) as TotalMTMPNL
from #TempData
left outer join #Profit2_Adjusted
on (#TempData.transactionId = #Profit2_Adjusted.closingtransactionId 
and datediff(d, #Profit2_Adjusted.ClosingDate, #TempData.Rundate) = 0 and #TempData.BuyOrSell = 'C' )
group by MasterEntity,Entity
order by MasterEntity,Entity
```

Comment: (32Red still in the history - better to delete the post and start again)

Comment: It definitely is a bad idea to write all this in MDX. You shouldn't look at exactly converting this SQL to MDX, but to have proper cube structures in place which does all the calculations while processing. That said, it is impossible for us to help you unless we have a clear picture of how your cube looks like, e.g. what are the dimensions, measures etc.

Comment: @SouravA : Just curious to know if we can apply multiple(five or six) transformations on the cube data based on the SSRS parameter value like start date and end date. this calculation can not be performed at the time of cube processing as it depends on the start and end date. MDX does not have temp table etc to save the intermediate transformation results.

Comment: Transformations?? You certainly can use parameters inside SSRS datasets that uses MDX. Those parameters in subjunction with `StrToSet` or `StrToMember` can change the output. MDX certainly doesn't give you temp tables, but it gives you named sets and query scoped calculated members to do some adhoc calculations inside your code.

Comment: Entity,MasterEntity,BuyOrSell,transactionId,closingtransactionId are the degenereate dimension in Fact_data.
rundate,TransactionDate are role based dimension to dim_date. Quantity2, Quantity1, Quantity3, Quantity4, Profit1, Profit2, Profit3 are the measures in Fact_data. on these, above mentioned calculation is possible or not?  By transformation, i mean the separate operation on the data.

Comment: @SouravA :  As all this calculation depends on the SSRS parameters, this can not be done during the cube processing. It has to be performed when user runs the report with date parameter values.

Comment: I can't comment in affirmative or negative based on the limited data you have provided. But looks to me you have all the attributes you want to display on rows and all the measures(facts) you want to display on columns. So I guess it should be possible with the help of a complicated `IIF` or `CASE` construct. The joining part is already taken care inside the cube's attribute relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87279/discussion-between-user2356907-and-sourava).